# Google Maps stuck in "Loading" when clicking Directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kmz

I'm currently experiencing an odd issue relating to Google Maps.  I'm using an external kmz file so the issue may lay there.  However, when you click on one of the icons on the map then click on Directions, Google maps gets stuck in a never ending loop of "Loading".

Eg: http://ninjaotter.com/gmap.html

Anyone experience/resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing your browser's cache and retry the same sequence of actions.